# What's up with the ば in this sentence?

Tags: parsing, conditionals

泥棒は３０代半ばだったと思います。=>
"I think that the thief was in their mid-thirties."

I'm not sure what ば is doing in this sentence. It seems like it would translate the same (and be 'legal') without it. The only use of ば I'm familiar with is with conditionals but this doesn't make any sense as a conditional, unless it's trying to express a "maybe" of some kind?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

半ば is read なかば for which you will find a dictionary entry.

Comment: Whooooops. Assumed I knew the reading and didn't check the furigana . Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

半ば is read なかば.  It's one word meaning "in the middle"